# How to automatically open a created text document after it being created

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs

I've used [this script](http://opensourcehacker.com/2013/01/21/script-for-generating-google-documents-from-google-spreadsheet-data-source/) to create a Google Document (like word document) with Google Spreadsheet. But, when I do so, the new text document created from a template is placed in the default chosen folder. And, after that, I have to go to that folder, find the new document and open it.

The million dollar question is: how could I make the newly created text document to automatically open? I think that if it wasn't a Google text Document but a spreadsheet I should use `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`. Is there a document equivalent of `.getActive()`?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found no direct way of opening a created document through Google Apps Script (GAS), via GAS. There's however an indirect way, which is presented below. It uses an Anchor element to show a pre-formatted hyperlink.

### Code

```
// global
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: "Create Document", functionName: "createDoc"}];
  ss.addMenu("Extra", menu);
}

function createDoc() {
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(), aRow = sh.getActiveCell().getRowIndex();
  var title = sh.getRange(aRow, 1).getValue(), docDate = new Date(); 
  var docTitle = title + "-" + docDate, doc = DocumentApp.create(docTitle);
  var url = doc.getUrl();

  // create app and panel
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Open Google Document")
    .setHeight(50).setWidth(400);
  var vPanel = app.createVerticalPanel()
    .add(app.createAnchor(docTitle, url));

  // add to app
  app.add(vPanel);
  ss.show(app);  
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Remarks

This piece of code creates a new menu entry called "Extra" upon opening of the file. The selection "Create Document" will create (in the back gound) a Google Document and displays a panel with a hyperlink to open the document.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: [How To Open Document](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdEtFLW8wejVGVGtyNkRSYUFUME9tb3c&usp=sharing)